# POST on /oauth/token always use client_secret_basic

Tags: flask, authlib

I'm trying to add oauth2 (server) on my flask app and I have some issues with the `/oauth/token` endpoint with `client_secret_post`.

My app does POST the following to it as a form:

```
client_id=XXX
client_secret=YYY
grant_type=client_credentials
token_endpoint_auth_method=client_secret_post
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/oauth-callback
```

And I get in the logs:

```
DEBUG:authlib.oauth2.rfc6749.authenticate_client:Authenticate None via "client_secret_basic" failed
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2019 18:05:26] "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.0" 401 -
```

The `token_endpoint_auth_method` doesn't seems to change anything and it always returns `{"error": "invalid_client"}`.

I have tried adding `TOKEN_ENDPOINT_AUTH_METHODS = ['client_secret_post']` to my `class AuthorizationCodeGrant(grants.AuthorizationCodeGrant):` without effects (also none of the loggers print anything).

What did I missed there ?

I have implemented things in my app more or less like the oauth2 flask example, here is some extracts:

app.py:

```
from app_oauth import config_oauth
...
def create_app(...):
    ...
    config_oauth(app)
    ...
```

app_oauth.py:

```
from authlib.flask.oauth2 import AuthorizationServer, ResourceProtector
from authlib.flask.oauth2.sqla import (
    create_query_client_func,
    create_save_token_func,
    create_revocation_endpoint,
    create_bearer_token_validator,
)
from authlib.oauth2.rfc6749 import grants
from werkzeug.security import gen_salt
from models import db, User
from models import OAuth2Client, OAuth2AuthorizationCode, OAuth2Token
from flask import current_app


class AuthorizationCodeGrant(grants.AuthorizationCodeGrant):
    def create_authorization_code(self, client, user, request):
        current_app.logger.debug("create auth code")

        code = gen_salt(48)
        item = OAuth2AuthorizationCode(
            code=code,
            client_id=client.client_id,
            redirect_uri=request.redirect_uri,
            scope=request.scope,
            user_id=user.get_user_id(),
        )
        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()
        return code

    def parse_authorization_code(self, code, client):
        current_app.logger.debug("parse auth code")

        item = OAuth2AuthorizationCode.query.filter_by(
            code=code, client_id=client.client_id).first()
        if item and not item.is_expired():
            return item

    def delete_authorization_code(self, authorization_code):
        current_app.logger.debug("delete auth code")

        db.session.delete(authorization_code)
        db.session.commit()

    def authenticate_user(self, authorization_code):
        current_app.logger.debug("auth user")

        return User.query.get(authorization_code.user_id)


class PasswordGrant(grants.ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant):
    def authenticate_user(self, username, password):
        current_app.logger.debug("password grant auth user")
        user = User.query.filter_by(name=username).first()
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user


class RefreshTokenGrant(grants.RefreshTokenGrant):
    def authenticate_refresh_token(self, refresh_token):
        current_app.logger.debug("refresh token grant")
        token = OAuth2Token.query.filter_by(refresh_token=refresh_token).first()
        if token and not token.revoked and not token.is_refresh_token_expired():
            return token

    def authenticate_user(self, credential):
        current_app.logger.debug("auth user grant user")

        return User.query.get(credential.user_id)


query_client = create_query_client_func(db.session, OAuth2Client)
save_token = create_save_token_func(db.session, OAuth2Token)
authorization = AuthorizationServer(
    query_client=query_client,
    save_token=save_token,
)
require_oauth = ResourceProtector()


def config_oauth(app):
    authorization.init_app(app)

    # support all grants
    authorization.register_grant(grants.ImplicitGrant)
    authorization.register_grant(grants.ClientCredentialsGrant)
    authorization.register_grant(AuthorizationCodeGrant)
    authorization.register_grant(PasswordGrant)
    authorization.register_grant(RefreshTokenGrant)

    # support revocation
    revocation_cls = create_revocation_endpoint(db.session, OAuth2Token)
    authorization.register_endpoint(revocation_cls)

    # protect resource
    bearer_cls = create_bearer_token_validator(db.session, OAuth2Token)
    require_oauth.register_token_validator(bearer_cls())
```

and my blueprint:

```
from app_oauth import authorization
...
@bp_api_v1_auth.route("/oauth/token", methods=["POST"])
def oauth_token():
    return authorization.create_token_response()
```

Edit: after digging it looks like it is handled by ClientCredentialsGrant which does only `client_secret_basic` by default, I then added:

```
class ClientCredentialsGrant(grants.ClientCredentialsGrant):
    TOKEN_ENDPOINT_AUTH_METHODS = [
        'client_secret_basic', 'client_secret_post'
    ]
...
    authorization.register_grant(ClientCredentialsGrant)
```

Which now validates but respond with `{"error": "unauthorized_client"}`

Answer (score 1):

Finally nailed it: my OAuth2Client entry in database had only `authorization_code` and `password`, `client_credentials` was needed to validate.